# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers Multiple Themes Not Working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a bit of a weird bug on a website I'm working on. I have multiple themes configured in the Forms Folders in Web Forms For Marketers. No matter what theme or color I select, all of my forms use the theme and color selected for the Website folder. I tested this with a clean install and it worked fine, this is a bug on my specific website.

Here's what I'm working with:

- CMS 6.5.0 rev. 120427
- DMS 2.0.1 rev.120427
- Web Forms for Marketers-2.3.0 rev. 120216

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. From Sitecore Support, when I raised the same issue a while back:

> Edited by Alexander Yaremenko on Thursday, November 18, 2010 at 2:10
>   PM
>
> Hi Mark,
>
> This is expected behavior. The Theme and Color defined for all forms
>   for the current site. If you run site (For example Site1) all web
>   forms will have themes from forms folder that defined in formsRoot
>   attribute for current site instead of theme from forms folder that
>   stored this form.
>
> I have registered a wish that we can change this behavior in future.
>
> I can't find the easier way to change this behavior now. I see only
>   one workaround: Create you custom control which will be insert link to
>   needed .css on the page. Note: the link to your .css should be defined
>   below then standard .css.

The Sitecore Support case reference is 336904.

In essence, WFFM assumes themes to be "per site", not multiple themes in the same site.